# Breaking early from a function

Tags: javascript, database, function, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase, and I'm trying to create a user balance. In which when a user purchases something, this value is taken away from their balance.

This currently works correctly, and updates on the firebase database. However, I can't seem to break from the loop which calculates the new balance. Therefore, the same calculation is repeated.

I've tried using `break` and `return` and can't seem to get anywhere.

```
function changeuserbal(coinwager){
var dbRoot = firebase.database().ref();
dbRoot.on("value", snap => {
    var cData = snap.val();
    var cBet = cData.coinbet;
    var uBal = cData.userbalance;
    var BalUp = uBal-cBet;
    alert(BalUp);
    firebase.database().ref("userbalance").set(BalUp);
});
}
```

I'm assuming because `firebase.database().ref("userbalance").set(BalUp);` restarts the loop. I've tried placing this outside, but I can't seem to pass BalUp outside of the loop.

Comment: I don't see any "loop" here.

Comment: @Pointy That's correct, but for my problem a loop was causing an issue, as when the data was updated the dbRoot.on would begin again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) sets up a listener that continually responds to changes at a location in the database.  It may be called repeatedly until you remove it. If you just want to read the data one time, use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) instead.

Comment: Yes, that's fixed it. I must've overlooked this. Thank you very much.